# Возврат значения (из ListView) в DialogFragment() Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, dialogfragment

Ищу решение, как получить выбранное значение (нажатие пользователем на пункт списка в окне диалога) из ListView в DialogFragment - Kotlin.

class DialogCategory : DialogFragment() {

```
private var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
private var dbHelper: DBHelper? = null
private var cursor: Cursor? = null

private val list: ListView? = null

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    dbHelper = DBHelper(context)
    db = dbHelper!!.writableDatabase
    cursor = db!!.query(TABLE_CATEGORY, arrayOf("_id", CATEGORY_NAME), null, null, null, null, null)
    val cursorAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor, arrayOf(CATEGORY_NAME),
            intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1), 0)
    if (list != null) {
        list.adapter = cursorAdapter
    }

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setTitle("Выберите категорию")
            builder.setAdapter(cursorAdapter) {dialog, which ->}
    return builder.create()
}
```

}

Comment: И? В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вторым параметром в listener передаётся позиция выбранного элемента, вы можете получить сам элемент у адаптера:

```
builder.setAdapter(cursorAdapter) { dialog, which ->
    val item = cursorAdapter.getItem(which)
}
```

Чтобы передать значение в `Activity`, нужно использовать интерфейс, например:

```
interface OnDialogItemSelected {
    fun onItemSelected(category: String)
}
```

Тогда его можно реализовать в `Activity`:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnDialogItemSelected {

    // other methods..

    override fun onItemSelected(category: String) {
        textView.text = category
    }
}
```

И использовать в `DialogFragment`:

```
class DialogCategory : DialogFragment() {

    // other fields..

    private lateinit var listener: OnDialogItemSelected

    // В этом методе фрагмент добавляется к Ativity и т.к. Activity реализует нужный нам интерфейс
    // можно использовать её в качестве листенера
    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        listener = context as OnDialogItemSelected
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        // other methods..            

        builder.setAdapter(cursorAdapter) { dialog, which ->
            val item = cursorAdapter.getItem(which)
            val category: String = "" // TODO: получить категорию из item
            listener.onItemSelected(category) // вызовется метод Activity

        }
        return builder.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: ок, спс попробую. Как принять ответ в активности которая создала диалог? В моем случае мне необходимо получить  String категории и вставить данное значение в textview. Изучая вопрос, гугл доки говорять необходимо использовать интерфейс для взаимодействия диалогов и Активити, но мне интересно узнать может есть более изящные решения. Спасибо.

Comment: Использование интерфейса и есть "изящное решение", остальные способы нарушают общепринятые правила для взаимодействия между Activity и Fragment )
Дополнил ответ с примером передачи строки.

А вот так можно сделать "некрасиво": `(activity as MyActivity).textView.text = category`

Comment: Еще раз СПАСИБО, благодаря Вашим рекомендациям + гугл доки + иные источники получил что хотел.!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Финальное решение**, может кому и пригодится. Еще раз вкратце пояню, что в данном примере решается.

1. Есть Активити которая вызывает Диалог
2. В Диалоге подкючаемся к SQLite и через адаптер выводим список строк таблицы по заданному столбцу (column)
3. Пользователь видит список и выбирает необходимую строку -> нажимает
4. Диалог возвращает значение (String) выбранной пользователем строки в Активити. Для возврата значения используется интерфейс **OnDialogItemSelected**. Активити должна реализовать метод **fun onItemSelected ()** (ну или точнее функцию т.к. Котлин) интерфейса  где возвращенное значение вставляется в TextView которое отображается в Активити. Вроде понятно расписал. 
   **Не судите строго, я сам еще начинающий. Стимулируюая критика для развития приветсвуется.**

Класс - AddExpenseActivity.kt вызывает диалог (DialogCategory.kt)

```
class AddExpenseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DialogCategory.OnDialogItemSelected { 

private lateinit var textViewCategory: TextView

override fun onItemSelected(category: String) {
    textViewCategory.text = category
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_expense)

    textViewCategory = findViewById(R.id.textView_category)
    textViewCategory.text = "category"
    textViewCategory.setOnClickListener {
        val manager = supportFragmentManager
        val dialog = DialogCategory()
        dialog.show(manager, "dialog") //вызов диалога
    }
}
```

class DialogCategory : DialogFragment() {

```
private var db: SQLiteDatabase? = null
private var dbHelper: DBHelper? = null
private var cursor: Cursor? = null
val TAG: String = "DialogCategory"

interface OnDialogItemSelected {
    fun onItemSelected(category: String)
}

private lateinit var listener: OnDialogItemSelected

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    listener = context as OnDialogItemSelected
}

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    dbHelper = DBHelper(context)
    db = dbHelper!!.writableDatabase
    cursor = db!!.query(TABLE_CATEGORY, arrayOf("_id", CATEGORY_NAME), null, null, null, null, null)
    var cursorAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor, arrayOf(CATEGORY_NAME),
            intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1), 0)

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setTitle("Выберите категорию")
    builder.setAdapter(cursorAdapter) { dialog, which ->
        val column: String = cursor!!.getColumnName(1) // 1 - это column таблицы
        val name:String = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(column))
        listener.onItemSelected(name)
    }
    return builder.create()
}
```

}